# Dataannotations to restrict numbers only using mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Can I restrict user to enter only numbers using DataAnnotations?

Below is the property which I have in my Model

```
[Display(Name = "Fiscal Year")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Fiscal Year is required")]
public int FiscalYear { get; set; }
```

Below is the definition which I am using in .chtml (razor view):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.project.FiscalYear)
```

I want to allow users only to enter numbers. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Balaji

Comment: Do you want the TextBox to not allow any characters to be entered other than numbers (e.g. Client-Side) or is it good enough to let the user enter invalid characters and submit the form and then get presented with an error (e.g. Server-Side)? If you want client-side restrictions, you will have to write some JavaScript to do it. If you only care about server-side, then the code you have should do the trick; MVC3 won't allow you to enter data other than an `int` for a ViewModel `int` property.

Comment: Wouldn't `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.project.FiscalYear)` work? (assuming you have unobtrusive validation enabled)

Answer (score 3):

Get the Nuget package called DataAnnotationsExtensions.. then use it like below:

```
    [Integer(ErrorMessage="This is needs to be integer")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
```

It will put the proper the validation in place assuming that you have jQuery validation plugin and unobtrusive validation enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegularExpression attribute